# Fuzz TCP client with Peach Fuzzer

Tags: tcpserver, fuzzing, peach

I want to fuzz a TCP clinet with Peach Fuzzer.
I found some examples for fuzzing TCP server.
But I can't any example for fuzzing TCP client.
Who can show me some examples for fuzzing TCP client or get me some ideas?

Comment: While older versions of Peach were open source, the newest version is commercial. Peach Fuzzer sells the "Peach Pit" files necessary to fuzz particular protocols.

Comment: Any alternative tool for TCP fuzzing?